# Why Perl regex capturing groups behave differently between `print` and arithmentic operations?

Tags: regex, perl, text-processing, capturing-group

In Perl (v5.30.0), regex are evaluated as the captures, when used as parameters of `print()`:

```sh
# Simplified example; the real case has more text, and the capture covers only part of it.

echo $'1\n2\n3' | perl -ne 'print /(.)/'
# 123
```

This is great for text extraction. I'd like to exploit the same convenience for arithmetic operations, but this doesn't work as expected:

```sh
# Attempt to compute a sum of the int value of the captures
#
echo $'1\n2\n3' | perl -ne '$tot += /(.)/; END { print $tot }'
# 3

# Attempt to print twice the int value of each capture
#
echo $'1\n2\n3' | perl -ne 'print(/(.)/ * 2)'
# 222
```

Using the capture variables work:

```sh
echo $'1\n2\n3' | perl -ne 'if (/(.)/) { $tot += $1 }; END { print $tot }'
# 6
```

However, I was curious why this happens, and if it's possible in any way to use the previous, more compact, form, in order to perform arithmetic operations on captured values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `m//` returns 1 for success in scalar context (see [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop)). You can enforce list context to return the matched part:

```sh
echo $'1\n2\n3' | perl -ne '$tot += (/(.)/)[0]; END { print $tot }'
```

Comment: Or `$tot += $1 if /(.)/;` or `$tot += $& if /./;`

Comment: The capture was already mentioned in the question. I tried to explain why a match can't be used directly and how you can use it without (it uses a capture under the hood).

Comment: Yup, just some alternatives

Comment: Can also use `for` for context: `perl -wE'$tot += $_ for "123" =~ /(.)/g; say $tot'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_` to add up all of the input:

```
echo $'1\n2\n3' | perl -ne '$tot += $_; END { print $tot . "\n" }'

6
```

Or else, you can use `-a` (autosplit) option to split input into fields:

```
echo $'1\n2\n3' | perl -ane '$tot += $F[0]; END { print $tot . "\n" }'

6
```

Comment: That autosplit is a no-op, just like `split ' ', "1\n"` would only split into 1 field. Basically the same as using `$_`, but obfuscated needlessly. If it was not a no-op, you would be discarding the rest of the data (if any).

Comment: Thanks @TLP. Sorry for being a naive. But I think if we want to use `$F[0]` then we'll need to use `-a` option.

Comment: Like I said, in this case `$F[0]` and `$_` is basically the same. The difference is that the split on `' '` will strip the newline.